# How to upload image or video from mobile device to content

Tags: 7, files, media

Creating node via mobile browser goes ok, but when adding image or video i can only record and upload which also works fine, but i can not access gallery and choose an image to upload.

Options available after clicking Choose file are:
- Camera
- Camcorder
- Voice Recorder
- Documents

Comment: Websites (built by Drupal or not) can't affect the functionality of the browser/OS it's being viewed in. Well, unless the browser/os provides a way. Either way, there's nothing Drupal can do to help, it depends what your device will let you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a mobile OS issue. But in general, documents will open a list and show file managers at the bottom.

Comment: It kinda does though. Opening documents and either using the built in browser or scrolling to the bottom for other apps is exactly how to do it.

Comment: It is indeed an answer (correct one at that) to the question. The question is just off-topic as it's not related to Drupal

Comment: Niall answer is good. It does the job. I never tried going into documents on Android to check whats inside. It is not user friendly but ill guide them so it will work.